# Estimation for $C_0$-semigroup

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

If we have some $C_0$-semigroup $(S(t))_{t\geq 0}$ and $\lVert u(t)\rVert\leq C$ for $t\in [0,T)$ and $u(0)=u_0$, why do we then have, for $0<t<t'<T$, the estimation 
$$
\lVert (S(t)-S(t'))u_0\rVert\leqslant C\lvert t-t'\rvert?
$$

This should be an easy consequence of the fact that $(S(t))$ is a $C_0$-semigroup but I do not see the reason.

Comment: Do you mean that it follows from the axioms of the $C^0$-semigroup?

Comment: This would be my conjecture. At least in the script there is the short remark: "$C_0$-semigroup: $t,t'>0$" to this estimate.

Comment: Do you know anything about $u$?

Comment: I guess that $u$ is a mild solution of a PDE $u_t=Au+F(u), u(0)=u_0$ where $S(t)$ is the solution Operator to $u_t=Au$, i.e. $u(t)=S(t)u_0+\int_{0}^t S(t-s)F(u(s))\, ds$.